# React Native Linking.openURL not working as expected in for loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, native, jsx

I am having trouble with Linking.openURL in one of my projects. Ill get straight to the point: I have an array of 5 links called "links" and I have a function that builds my GUI to an array called "text".

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 4; i++){
      await text.push(
          <View>
          <Text style={{color: '#3498db', marginBottom:5, textAlign:"left"}} onPress={async () => await Linking.openURL(links[i])}>
           {titles[i]}
           {"\n"}
           {links[i]}
           </Text>
          </View>
        )
        }
```

As you can see from above, i have a title associated with each link that is also an array called "titles". This function creates a view with 5 titles in it, and when you click each title it should redirect you to the corresponding link using, linking.openURL(links[i]). However, what actually does end up happening is that all 5 titles point to the same link, the last link in my array, links[4]. I thought my code was buggy so I added this line: {links[i]} to display my links next to each of my titles. However, i was even more baffled, as it displays the correct link next to each title, however when trying to open up any of the titles it directs you to the 5th link URL. Am i implementing linking.openURL in a wrong manner? (I also tried created a 'var dumbyLink = links[i]' at the beginning of the for loop and then doing 'linking.openURL(dumbyLink)' because I thought that links[i] might not be getting evaluated right away, but this still didn't work.)

Edit:
Just to make sure that the linking.openURL was indeed oddly receiving the last link, i used this code:

```
onPress={async () => await Linking.openURL(links[i]).then(Alert.alert(links[i].toString()))}>
```

and got an Alert of the 5th link when pressing any title, however {links[i]} still displayed the correct information and that line comes after the linking.openURL code in the for loop so I am confused.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaking your problem where you need to open the respective link and you are ending up opening same link from all tiles.
Then Solution to your problem is FlatList :

```
//display and style your elements
renderItem = ({item}) => {
      return (
        <Text style={{color: '#3498db', marginBottom:5, textAlign:"left"}} onPress={() => Linking.openURL(item)}>
         {item}
         </Text>
      )
    } 



render() {
      const extractKey = (item,index) => index
      let list = ['https://www.google.com', 'https://www.facebook.com', 'https://www.stackoverflow.com', 'https://www.github.com',
      'https://www.yahoo.com']; //random links
      return (
        <FlatList
          data={list}
          renderItem={(item) => this.renderItem(item)}
          keyExtractor={extractKey}
          />
        );
    }
```

The above code is tested on RN 0.47.1 .Hope your confusion is clear.